# NullPointerException downloading pdf file from azure app service, Spring-boot Java 8

Tags: azure, spring-boot, java-8, azure-web-app-service

I have a spring boot application with Java 8 in which I can create and download a PDF file with Itext PDF library, **in local and development environment this works fine** but when I deploy the application in my azure app service  I can't download this file, I had a NullPointerException.

```
2020-11-24T13:04:12.310887019Z: [INFO]  ****Downloading PDF file: /home/site/descargas/
2020-11-24T13:04:13.814155878Z: [INFO]  *** ERROR : java.lang.NullPointerException
2020-11-24T13:04:13.815304521Z: [ERROR]  com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: java.lang.NullPointerException
2020-11-24T13:04:13.816149053Z: [ERROR]     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:821)
2020-11-24T13:04:13.816580670Z: [ERROR]     at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:277)
```

And my code is:

```
document = new Document();      
            FileOutputStream coursesFile = new FileOutputStream(DIRECTORIO_TEMP+"cursos.pdf");  

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, coursesFile);
            PDFEvent eventoPDF = new PDFEvent();
            writer.setPageEvent(eventoPDF);
            document.open();                
            //margenes de documento         
            document.setMargins(45, 45, 80, 40);        
                        
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] {15,35,50,10});     
            table.setWidthPercentage(100);          
            table.getDefaultCell().setPaddingBottom(20);
            table.getDefaultCell().setPaddingTop(20);       
            Stream.of("ID", "Área", "Nombre", "Horas").forEach(columnTitle -> {
                PdfPCell header = new PdfPCell();                   
                header.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_INFRA);         
                header.setBorderWidth(1);                           
                header.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);                        
                header.setPhrase(new Phrase(columnTitle, fuenteCabecera));
                table.addCell(header);
            });
            for (Curso curso : cursos) {
                table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table.addCell(new Phrase(curso.getCodigoCurso(), fuenteNegrita ) );
                table.addCell(new Phrase(curso.getAreaBean().getNombre_area(), fuenteNormal ));
                table.addCell(new Phrase(curso.getNombreCurso(), fuenteNormal ));
                PdfPCell celdaHoras = new PdfPCell( new Phrase(curso.getHoras() + "", fuenteNormal ) );
                celdaHoras.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table.addCell(celdaHoras);

            }
            
            document.add(new Paragraph(Chunk.NEWLINE));
            document.add(new Paragraph(Chunk.NEWLINE));
            document.add(table);                        
            document.close();   
            coursesFile.close();
```

The file permission in my Azure app service are:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Newest**

**Answer For Linux：**

I don't know what method you used to deploy the whole process of webapp. However, the `descargas` folder will not be created automatically in any way.

No matter what method you use to deploy the webapp, it is recommended that you log in to kudu and check the `descargas` folder and whether the files under the folder exist. It is not recommended to use `FTP` to upload.

In addition, there should be no concept of `D:\` drive and virtual application under `Linux`. It is recommended to use `relative paths` in the code to read files.

And

**PRIVIOUS**

**Answer For Windows：**

This error occurs because the access path must be wrong. I don't know if your code uses a relative path or an absolute path.

**So my advice is:**

1. Use absolute paths to access files.

I have test and it works for me, both in my local and on azure.

The file path like `D:\home\site\myfiles\a.pdf` .

2. Use virtual directories to access files

You also can use `Virtual Directory` to access your file, the path you access by broswer,like `https://www.aa.azurewebsites.net/myfiles/a.pdf`,  and you also can check it by kudu, like `D:\home\site\myfiles\a.pdf`.

For more details, you can refer to the offical doc,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#windows-apps-uncontainerized .

Comment: I used the absolute path too but doesn't work. I don't understand why works in all my enviroments but in Azure doesn't

Comment: @LuisManrique It is recommended that you still use remote debug to determine the source of the problem.

Comment: @LuisManrique Did you try to use `Virtual Directory`?